# how to close jsf dialog box popup in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, jsf-2.2

I am trying to close the dialog box of a JSF Popup through selenium script. But i am unable to find the `XPath` of the Cross Sign of that specific popup window.
How do i achieve this. I tried debugging in Firefox but to no success. 
Any help much appreciated.?

Comment: Compulsory to click on that close button? If not you can try with simulating keys to close may escape etc..